How to send data when my card triggers automatically
I'm working with botframework and I need some data to be send even if the card is triggered automatically.
Here is how my actionSet is defined
{
          "type": "ActionSet",
          "actions": [
              {
                  "type": "Action.Execute",
                  "title": "Guardar",
                  "verb": "actionExecutedByStatusSelectionCard",
                  "data": {
                      "ActionableMessage_ID": "${ActionableMessage_ID}",
                      "FieldToEdit": "_Estado",
                      "EntityId": "${EntityId}",
                      "InstanceId": "${InstanceId}",
                      "MerlinAPIURL": "${MerlinAPIURL}",
                      "MerlinUser": "${MerlinUser}",
                      "MerlinPassword": "${MerlinPassword}"
                  },
                  "fallback": "Action.Submit"
              }
          ]
      }

I need MerlinUser and MerlinPassword always to be sent.
This is what I get if the card is triggered automatically(Notice that Data comes empty).

I have no clue about what to try.

Could you please specify which channel you’re referring to (e.g., Microsoft Teams, WebChat, Emulator). If the data property is not working and returns empty, it appears that there might be an issue with your code. Atleast the property should exist with a null or empty value. Also, I noticed that the property is not displayed in the screenshot. Please review your code to ensure it is working as expected.

I found that in order to send data when the card refreshes, you need to add the data you want to send in the refresh key of the card, like this:
"refresh": {
    "action": {
      "type": "Action.Execute",
      "title": "Submit",
      "verb": "personalDetailsCardRefresh",
      "data": {
        "ActionableMessage_ID": "${ActionableMessage_ID}",
        "MerlinAPIURL": "${MerlinAPIURL}",
        "MerlinUser": "${MerlinUser}",
        "MerlinPassword": "${MerlinPassword}"
      }
    },

This way, when the user opens up the message, this data will be sent automatically.
